# TensorFlow Lite in Qt with cmake in WSL

Tags: qt, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I want to work with tensorflow lite in the qt creator (cmake), which is running in the WSL. The project is to be build for arm. I have found this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake

I am struggling with the CMakeLists.txt to find the correct source folder of tensorflow lite.

[error & folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FYgs.png)

Comment: Can you show your directory structure? Is it the same as for that example `CMakeLists.txt` file?

Comment: I have added a picture to the question

Comment: It does not show whether the tensor flow source is under ../../../../ as per the CMakeLists.txt file.

Comment: Ah ok, I got it. The picture shows all what I have, but  I don`t have so many subfolders. "tensorflow_src", "tflite_build" and the project "tfTest" are on the same level. What do I have to adjust in the CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to adjust this part in your `CMakeLists.txt`. This is referencing to the tensor flow source four directories up in the parent hierarchy.

But it looks like that your project layout is slightly different based on your comment. So, this is where you will need to make the adjustment according to the needs of your project.

```
if(NOT TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR)
  get_filename_component(TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../../../../" ABSOLUTE)
endif()
```

Comment: Ok, but is it enough to adjust only the path? I have the two folders "tensorflow_src" and "tflite_build" from the instructions. Don't the two folders have to be used somewhere in CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: As the TENSORFLOW_SOURCE_DIR name indicates, this refers to the tensorflow_src directory.